# Django natural keys, combination of two values?

Tags: python, django, django-models, key

I would like to make a natural key for a Model that is the combination of two values.

I have attempted the following:

```
class TeamManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)

class Team(models.Model):
    objects = TeamManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def natural_key(self):
        return name

class SeasonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, team, year):
        return self.get(team=team.natural_key(), year=year)

class Season(models.Model):
    objects = SeasonManager()
    year = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=YEARS)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

    def natural_key(self):
        return "%s-%s"%(self.team.natural_key(),self.year)

    natural_key.dependencies = ['league.Team']
```

When I attempt to access the Season model via its natural key "Atlanta Falcons", "2013-1014" I get this exception:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Atlanta Falcons'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning string of you 2 values as natural key return tupple of those as

```
def natural_key(self):
    return (self.team.natural_key(),self.year)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following fix works for me:

```
class SeasonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, team, year):
        return self.get(team=Team.objects.get_by_natural_key(team), year=year)
```